# OnMapReady not called when screen is rotated

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I have a ViewPager that has a SupportMapFragment in it. Below is a snippet of the Activity's onCreate method.

```
    ...
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentAdapter.getItem(0);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ...
```

I can get access to the GoogleMap in the OnMapReady callback. But when the screen is rotated, the onMapReady is not called anymore. I am using FragmentPagerAdapter (and have tried FragmentStatePagerAdapter but still the same). How can I make the SupportMapFragment call OnMapReady when screen is rotated? I can probably use the deprecated method getMap() but if there is a way not to use it, it would be better.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with your application flow if you need the onMapReady to be called ever time you want to work with the map (or maybe I have misunderstood you). Can you share the relevant parts of your Activity?

Comment: I am using places api to search for a place. When a user picks a place, I want to move and zoom in to that place, so I need to have a reference of the map. But when the screen is rotated, I lose the reference of the map so I  need to get another reference. But the correct way of retrieving a reference of the map is through OnMapReady callback, since getMap of SupportMapFragment is already deprecated.

Comment: are you sure you don't override "onConfigurationChanges" in your activity?